# Exporting Data from Google Analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I working on Ruby on Rails application using a PostgreSQL database. I have heard of the [Data Export API for GA](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html).  However, after reading through there documentation I am still a little confused about how to export the data.

To summarize, my goal is to export the summary data from GA, turn it into a csv file, and then insert it into my database. Any direction in terms of how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the [Data Export API Client Libraries & Sample Code](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataLibraries.html#otherLibraries)

There are some Ruby examples in there.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out the [Google Analytics App Gallery](http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/).  Here you will find many 3rd party tools that may do most of the programming for you.