# How to export complete Google Analytics historical data?

Tags: google-analytics, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I was given a few days to export all the historical data from a Google Analytics account before access will be shutoff. Important to note that you cannot migrate historical data (at the time of this post) from one Google Analytics account to another. I would specifically like to program this for Excel or better yet get guidance on what others have used.

I have never done this before so wanted to reach out and see what others have used? Wanted to avoid the Google Analytics Data Export API unless there was no other option. There is about 5 years of data for a very active site.

### Update

I decided moving the information manually was the best route to go at that time. There may be new solutions, see links below.

Related references that may be helpful to others:

[Account merge and data move options](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1109839?hl=en)
[Developers.Google.Com](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts?csw=1#organization) - Google Dev Guide
[Can we move Google Analytics data to other account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278914/can-we-move-google-analytics-data-to-other-account)
[Exporting Data from Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859777/exporting-data-from-google-analytics) - Trying to avoid the API
[Google Analytics Application Gallery](http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/) - Apps list, anyone use these?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't (not with the free version of GA in any case). You can export aggregated reports (with up to 50 000 rows for standard reports or 200 000 rows for ad-hoc (not pre-calculated) reports via the API either by scripting yourself or using a tool like Next Analytics (the only programm from the Application Gallery I have used myself). But with 5 years of data you will at some point hit the courtesy limits for the Google API. And I'm not sure how helpful the exports are when you cannot get at the raw data.

Data Liberation from google may contanin updated info about this topic https://sites.google.com/a/dataliberation.org/www/google/analytics

Comment: Thank you Eike I ended up going into standard reports and just going down the entire left column (Audience, Traffic Sources, Content, Conversion) and pulled an Excel / PDF of everything. Took me a couple hours but that should help. I also ran some custom reports for SEO specific metrics.

Comment: Sometimes the manual way is the quickest!

Comment: If google has more access to the data than you do, who really owns it.  :S

Answer (score 1):

This is a late reply but for the benefit of others, I would like to chime in here.
The only way I have found is to use Google Analytics API but from experience this is extremely complicated for non-programmers. Here is a [google anlaytics datawarehouse](http://www.infocaptor.com/google-analytics-datawarehouse.php) that will allow you extract data from any date in time and keep building history on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you write a cron that gatherers your current day-2 and as well as all the days-2 of 5 yrs
So every day by the end of the yr you will be having your complete data that too without breaking the limits of Google